# How to sum same column value of different rows in foreign table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table named table1 (table1_id,table1_exp) where table1_exp is foreign key linked with table2 (table2_exp,table2_num)
I want to sum all the table2_num of a same table1_id and then display it as one row.

Comment: You want a sum of foreign key values? That doesn't sound like it makes much sense. A simple `SELECT table1_id, sum(table1_exp) FROM table1 GROUP BY table1_id;` should do that. But I suspect you want something different. If so, please elaborate.

Comment: Please post table definitions and some sample data

Comment: Question updated

Comment: table id has multiple experiences (type number). I want to sum all its experiences and display in one row

Comment: Question updated please review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood, these are your tables:

```
t1 (table1_id , 
    table_1_exp)
t2 (table2_exp references table_1_exp,
    table2_num)
```

If that's so,

```
select t1.table1_id, 
       sum(t2.table2_num) sum_num
from t2 join t1 on t2.table2_exp = t1.table1_exp
group by t1.table1_id
```

might be what you want.

Though, I don't understand what "display as one row" means. Each `TABLE1_ID`'s sum would be in one row ... Sample data & expected output would help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use group by :

```
SELECT TABLE1_ID, SUM(T1.table1_exp) FROM TABLE1 T1 GROUP BY T1.TABLE1_ID
```